# If $X$ is random variable with possible values of $0, 2, 3$ and their probabilities being $0.3, 0.1, 0.6$ respectively, what is the EY and DY

Tags: probability, expected-value

Calculate the $EY$ and $DY$ if $Y=3(X-1)^2$. As I understand, $EY$ is calculated the same way $EX$ would be, only in this case first the value of a function must be calculated where $X$ denotes random variables. So, $EY=3\cdot 0.3 + 3 \cdot 0.1 + 12 \cdot = 1,92.$ But I have a problem with $DY$. The formula given is $$D(X)=M\left[ (X-M(X))^2  \right]=M((X-1,92)^2)=0.3 \cdot 3.69+0.1\cdot 0.64 + 0.6 \cdot 1.17= 0.12+0.06+0.7=0.25$$

It seems like a really small value, so I assume it's wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: $EY=3\cdot 0.3 + 3 \cdot 0.1 + 12 \cdot 0.6$ which is more than $1.92$  and $DY=(-5.4)^2\cdot 0.3 + (-5.4)^2 \cdot 0.1 + 3.6^2 \cdot 0.6$ which is a lot more than $0.25$

Comment: I am not understanding how you are defiining $M$. Presumably $M(Y) = \mathbb E[Y]$, but who is $M$ by itself? Are you wanting to compute
$$
\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y])^2],
$$
which is just the variance of $Y$?